# AMP Add a class after an event

Tags: events, triggers, amp-html

The only relevant thing I have is the "toggle" event, but nothing related to just add a class when I trigger an event in AMP.

I have a form to submit, and I want to add a class to a father element to change the color of the background so that I can show a different "look" for the success than the form.

How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<amp-state id="className">
   <script type="application/json">
    {
         "changeClass": ""
    }
   </script>
</amp-state>

 <p 
   class="beforeclick" 
   [class]="className.changeClass == 'newClass' ? 'afterclick' : 'beforeclick' 
   ">Hello World
 </p>

 <button on="tap:AMP.setState({className:{changeClass: 'newClass'})">Click</button>
```

When u click to the button it will look for the changeClass varibale to ClassName state and assign the newClass value to it .
And that value will assign to dynamic [class] and change the class value to new value.
it is pretty simple.

Comment: Thank you, so it is about tracking the status of the class. Therefore you can confirm me that we can only be able to "toggling" class, and not just add an extra one? There is no corrispective of $("myTarget").addClass("myClassName") in Jquery, right?

Comment: no u can change class or even change text. its some kind of data binding.
and yes u can add class like jquery but u may have to define static class first (not 100% sure about it).
for more info u can checkout this link: https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-bind

Comment: @Littlemad you can not use jQuery in amp

Comment: yeah @BachchaSingh I know I was trying to express myself with something that I knew howto.